# iOS 9 : Add Action When Push "Back To App" Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9.3

I've created 2 app. The first app can send value to the second app to process (URL Scheme). After success in the second app, it can open the first app and give a response using UIButton. but how to detect "back to app" is pressed so I can add action to give response to the first app?

Is there any delegate at "back to app" button? I want to show alert before "back to app" start switching app to previous app.

Comment: Dont think its possible, you can check this for more answer [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299044/sharing-file-data-between-applications-in-swift-ios)

Comment: Maybe you can use shared app groups http://stackoverflow.com/a/27730754/1489885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are asking for is not possible. Users, not apps, are supposed to be in control of which app is in the foreground.

Refer

[Bring previous app back to the front when user is done with my iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447101/bring-previous-app-back-to-the-front-when-user-is-done-with-my-ios-app)

Comment: is there any way to hide "back to app" button ?

Comment: How does Google GBoard iOS keyboard do it then? When microphone is clicked it swithes to it's own Speech-to-text app and as soon as you finished dictation it comes back to the previous app just like back-to-app button.