# Sharing Data Between Applications with different App ID Prefix in iOS

Tags: ios, caching, data-sharing

I've done some research on how to share data between apps. The most appealing approach is to use App Groups but that requires same app ID prefix. I know there are some similar questions on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find a suitable solution for my case.

I am building a framework which provides image and video. My goal is to create a shared cache mechanism so different apps on the same device that use my framework don't have to cache the same content twice. Ideally the cache can be used by different apps developed by different developers. Is this even possible?

Similiar questions:

[Sharing data in between apps in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652795/sharing-data-in-between-apps-in-ios)

[Sharing File Data Between Applications in Swift/iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299044/sharing-file-data-between-applications-in-swift-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Since the two apps are not part of the same app group they can not share any resources. The use of a common framework is irrelevant. The two apps will each have their own sandbox with no common area for the framework code to share.

The end result is each app using the framework will end up with its own copy of the cache.